# Continue with previous downloaded session without using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, ios

By using the ASIHTTPRequest and ASIDownloadCache i am able to continue with previous downloaded session.Now I don't want to use ASIDownloadCache.So,is there any alternatives to achieve it.
                                    Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the server supports it, you can specify the Content-Range field in the header of your HTTP request and ask only for a small portion of the file at once. When you get all portions, you can assemble the file together.

You can set HTTP headers with `NSMutableURLRequest setValue:@"0-1023/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Range"];`, this example downloads only the 1024 byte of the file. See also Content-Range in http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

This way you can download the file in parts and next time when you want to resume the download you can continue it from the next part that you don't have yet.